# handling multiple array selects

Tags: jquery

I have a form that begins with one select inside a div element.  If the user wants to add another year, they click 'Add Another Year' which copies the div element below and clones it.

```
<div class="inputfield" id="modelyeardiv" class="modelyeardiv">
    <select name="frmyears[]" tabindex="3">
        <option value="0000">-- SELECT A YEAR --</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
     </select>
     <a href="#" class="addmodelyear">Add Another Year</a>
</div>
```

Clicking 'Add Another Year' allows me to clone it so that the user can select multiple years.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.addmodelyear', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#modelyeardiv').after($('#modelyeardiv').clone());
    return false;
});
```

Now when my form submits, I want to check if there is only one frmyears[] present.  And if there is, I want to make sure the option value select is not 0000.  This will force the user to select at least one year.

How should I go about this?  I thought about creating a tracker within the jquery code above.  So I'd increment it by 1 each time 'Add Another Year' is clicked.  Upon submit, my jquery code would check this tracker.  If it's 1, then see if the value is 0000 and prompt the user if so.

Is the efficient?  Is there another way to accomplish this?

As a side note -- the client wants multiple drop downs like this.  He does not want a  multiple="multiple" list.

Comment: If there's more than one year dropdown, you might still want to check that at least one of them was changed from 0000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS/jQuery selector ":selected:not([value=0000])" should do the trick:

```
if($("#modelyeardiv :selected:not([value=0000])").length == 0) {
    // User has not selected a year
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are the `<select>` elements inside the form that will be submitted? If so, I think it would be simpler to just check how many of them you have with the name `frmyears[]` and if only one, then check the selected value, when the form is submitted. Something like

```
$(document).on("submit", "form", function(e) {

    var selects = $(this).find("select[name='frmyears[]']");

    if (selects.length === 1 && selects.val() === "0000") {
        // stop form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // do something else
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean that they can only pick one from each select box but can have multiple select box?

if so, just clone the select box with the same attribute name, then the values will be submit in an array i.e. request.getParameterValues("frmyears") will return the array of selected years

```
<div class="inputfield" id="modelyeardiv" class="modelyeardiv">
    <select name="frmyears" tabindex="3" multiple>
        <option value="0000">-- SELECT A YEAR --</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I was overthinking this problem.

```
if($('select[name="frmyears[]"]').length === 1) {
    alert('only one year -- check if its 0000');
}
```